# VSCode Clear results / disable debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have installed a custom debugger (not extension) via npm/git clone that now debugs everything when I start a specific file for Solidity (ethereum).
Now I tried to uninstall it but it still debugs it on launch of VS Code.
It then shows over 400 warnings because I don't use space or other small issues.
The warnings annoy me and drive me crazy.

How can I completely disable the debugger or delete all warnings that I find under "Problems"?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "npm uninstall annoying-debugger-package"?

Comment: @reggaeguitar Hi, yes sure. I have the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kodebox.solidity-language-server#review-details installed and once I create a new workspace, it automatically debugs. I have added the settings "solidity.solhint.enabled": false,
    "solidity.solium.enabled": false,
    "solidity.compilerOptions.optimizer.enabled": false, ad even uninstalled solhint and solium but it still debugs somehow and I can't find out why. The debugger I also uninstalled and found out, that the problem comes from the extension. When I deactivate the extension, it does not debug